# Is "Do not entry" a correct sentence in english?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is the sentence "Do not entry" correct?  I am asking about "Do not Entry" because I am writing about an Italian splatter movie and there is a scene where you can see a sign with that phrase. It appears in "The Beyond" (1981) from Lucio Fulci:

[image]

Since I am not a native English speaker I am thinking about it: is this a funny error or grammatically correct?

Comment: "Do Not Enter" or "No Entry" are more typical wordings.  Is one of these what you saw?

Comment: What film? (....)

Comment: It's the mistake of the film makers, and is listed in the "goofs" section of IMDB - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082307/trivia?tab=gf&ref_=tt_trv_gf  I don't think this was intentional as this is an Italian film set in the USA.

Comment: @Esti All of the additional information you have provided in comments should have been edited into the question (and if you have a screencap of  the sign which can be added, even better). Always provide as much information in questions as you possibly can: don't leave people to guess about what motivated you to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not entry is not correct.

*Do not enter*, *No entry*, *Entry prohibited*, etc are acceptable and are grammatically correct.

What you saw might be an error or probably an attempt at humour.

Comment: I've downvoted to offset the acceptance of your answer. A question such as this is not suitable for ELU; answering such questions sends out a wrong signal to the user base. This question should rather be close-voted as containing no supporting evidence (eg 'AHDEL, Collins, ODO ... do not list 'entry' as a verb') or for being otherwise not of a suitable standard.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer because: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346505/term-for-her-husband-when-she-is-dead/346508#comment802011_346508

Comment: A question too basic to be in scope of ELU should be migrated to the English learners site.